# Normalize nested json response into a dataframe with arbitrary level of nesting with non-consistent key

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am struggling to convert a JSON response into a pandas dataframe which I would like to use for various other operations. I have tried the methods listed [here](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas?select=raw_nyc_phil.json). But the issue is I cannot use `json_normalize` effectively since if I pass the required key as `record_path` parameter it is throwing error as only some fields have this key not all.
I am not wanting to iterate over the whole JSON and compare keys one by one and recreate my own dictionary object.
I want to get dataframe with `uuid` and `nice_to_have_skills`, `nice_to_have_skills_path`, `nice_to_have_experience` as columns where those `nice_to_have` attributes can be found inside the json object under `nice_to_have` and `operands` key.

A sample JSON response is here

> ```
> {   "hits": [
> {
>   "uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
>   "text_about": "some_text",
>   "objectID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-text_about"
> },
> {
>   "uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
>   "search_space": "some json object",
>   "is_searchspace": true,
>   "objectID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-search_space"
> },
> {
>   "uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
>   "nice_to_have": [
>     {
>       "operator": "AND",
>       "operands": [
>         {
>           "category": "Skill",
>           "values": [
>             {
>               "value": "MySQL ",
>               "clusters": []
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ],
>   "objectID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-nice_to_have"
> },
> {
>   "uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
>   "must_have": [
>     {
>       "operator": "AND",
>       "operands": [
>         {
>           "category": "Skill",
>           "values": [
>             {
>               "value": "React ",
>               "clusters": []
>             },
>             {
>               "value": "Node.js ",
>               "clusters": []
>             },
>             {
>               "value": "WebSocket ",
>               "clusters": []
>             },
>             {
>               "value": "JavaScript ",
>               "clusters": []
>             }
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "category": "Experience",
>           "values": [
>             {
>               "value": "3 yrs",
>               "clusters": []
>             }
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "operator": "OR",
>           "operands": [
>             {
>               "category": "Location",
>               "values": [
>                 {
>                   "value": "Toronto, Ontario, Canada (No Visa Sponsorship)",
>                   "clusters": []
>                 }
>               ]
>             },
>             {
>               "category": "Remote",
>               "values": [
>                 {
>                   "value": "Anywhere in the world",
>                   "clusters": []
>                 }
>               ]
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ],
>   "objectID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-must_have"
> },
> {"some key":"some json object"},
> {
>   "uuid": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
>   "text_about": "some text",
>   "objectID": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001-text_about"
> },
> {
>   "uuid": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
>   "search_space": "some json object",
>   "is_searchspace": true,
>   "objectID": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001-search_space"
> },
> {
>   "uuid": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
>   "nice_to_have": [
>     {
>       "operator": "AND",
>       "operands": [
>         {
>           "category": "Skill",
>           "values": [
>             {
>               "value": "Frontend Programming Language ",
>               "clusters": [
>                 {
>                   "key": "Programming Language~>Frontend Programming Language",
>                   "name": "Frontend Programming Language",
>                   "path": [
>                     "Programming Language",
>                     "Frontend Programming Language"
>                   ],
>                   "uuid": "e8c5cc6c-d92b-4098-8965-41e6818fe337",
>                   "category": "skill",
>                   "pretty_lineage": [
>                     "Programming Language"
>                   ]
>                 }
>               ]
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ],
>   "objectID": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001-nice_to_have"
> },
> {
>   "uuid": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
>   "must_have": [
>     {
>       "operator": "AND",
>       "operands": [
>         {
>           "category": "Remote",
>           "values": [
>             {
>               "value": "New Delhi (UTC+0530) 9am-6pm | 100.0% overlap",
>               "clusters": []
>             }
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "category": "Skill",
>           "values": [
>             {
>               "value": "User Research ",
>               "clusters": []
>             },
>             {
>               "value": "Wireframing / Prototyping ",
>               "clusters": [
>                 {
>                   "key": "Wireframing / Prototyping",
>                   "name": "Wireframing / Prototyping",
>                   "path": [
>                     "Wireframing / Prototyping"
>                   ],
>                   "uuid": "39fb1722-f522-4c66-90c5-5ee1cc525ff4",
>                   "category": "skill",
>                   "pretty_lineage": []
>                 }
>               ]
>             }
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "category": "Experience",
>           "values": [
>             {
>               "value": "2 yrs",
>               "clusters": []
>             }
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "category": "Other",
>           "values": [
>             {
>               "value": "Immediate Joiners Only",
>               "clusters": []
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ],
>   "objectID": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001-must_have"
> },
> {"some_key":"some json object"}   ] }
> ```

And I want to extract `"nice_to_have_skill" -> ["user research", "Wireframing / Prototyping"]` like this in my dataframe where `nice_to_have_skill` will be the column name and `["user research", "Wireframing / Prototyping"]` will be a value in that column.

EDIT :
How to deal with the JSON if it is of arbitrary depth?
E.G.

> {"nice_to_have": [{"operator": "AND", "operands": [{"operator": "OR",
> "operands": [{"category": "Language", "values": [{"value": " Korean",
> "clusters": []}]}]}]}], "company_name": "Framework", "company_role":
> ["Manufacturing", "Supply Chain/Procurement"]}
> Is a part of the JSON and there could be any level of nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `d['hits']` to [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) results in:

```
d = json.loads(json_text)

In [136]: %time pd.json_normalize(d['hits'])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
CPU times: user 2.1 ms, sys: 41 µs, total: 2.14 ms
Wall time: 2.12 ms
Out[136]: 
                                   uuid text_about                                           objectID      search_space is_searchspace                                       nice_to_have                                          must_have          some key          some_key
0  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  some_text    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-text_about               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN               NaN               NaN
1  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000        NaN  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-search_space  some json object           True                                                NaN                                                NaN               NaN               NaN
2  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000        NaN  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-nice_to_have               NaN            NaN  [{'operator': 'AND', 'operands': [{'category':...                                                NaN               NaN               NaN
3  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000        NaN     00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-must_have               NaN            NaN                                                NaN  [{'operator': 'AND', 'operands': [{'category':...               NaN               NaN
4                                   NaN        NaN                                                NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN  some json object               NaN
5  10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001  some text    10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001-text_about               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN               NaN               NaN
6  10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001        NaN  10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001-search_space  some json object           True                                                NaN                                                NaN               NaN               NaN
7  10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001        NaN  10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001-nice_to_have               NaN            NaN  [{'operator': 'AND', 'operands': [{'category':...                                                NaN               NaN               NaN
8  10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001        NaN     10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001-must_have               NaN            NaN                                                NaN  [{'operator': 'AND', 'operands': [{'category':...               NaN               NaN
9                                   NaN        NaN                                                NaN               NaN            NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN               NaN  some json object
```

there you can select `nice_to_have`:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=['hits'])

In [263]: %time df['nice_to_have'].dropna().sum()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
CPU times: user 705 µs, sys: 11 µs, total: 716 µs
Wall time: 713 µs
Out[263]: 
[{'operator': 'AND',
  'operands': [{'category': 'Skill',
    'values': [{'value': 'MySQL ', 'clusters': []}]}]},
 {'operator': 'AND',
  'operands': [{'category': 'Skill',
    'values': [{'value': 'Frontend Programming Language ',
      'clusters': [{'key': 'Programming Language~>Frontend Programming Language',
        'name': 'Frontend Programming Language',
        'path': ['Programming Language', 'Frontend Programming Language'],
        'uuid': 'e8c5cc6c-d92b-4098-8965-41e6818fe337',
        'category': 'skill',
        'pretty_lineage': ['Programming Language']}]}]}]}]
```

Hope this serves.

EDIT:

Responding to your comment: The main problem with this json is that the levels are inconsistent so the normalization cannot be performed and KeyError are raised.

A workaround to get the `nice_to_have`:

```
f = list(filter(lambda x: 'nice_to_have' in x, d['hits']))  

>> pd.json_normalize(f, ['nice_to_have', 'operands', 'values', 'clusters'])

                                                 key                           name                                               path                                  uuid category          pretty_lineage
0  Programming Language~>Frontend Programming Lan...  Frontend Programming Language  [Programming Language, Frontend Programming La...  e8c5cc6c-d92b-4098-8965-41e6818fe337    skill  [Programming Language]
```

From there you can get the values you want to get. A similar workaround can be applied to get the `must_have`.

Comment: yes, I figured that out, should have mentioned as well in the question. but is there any way to pass nice_to_have as root in json_normalise so that I can unnest that field as well?

Comment: oh, great example fo using lambda and filter! thanks!